# How to convert richtext document inlines back to Label

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, richtextbox

I have a WPF richtextbox custom control. And have added different inlines to Richtextbox paragraph by

```
Label curToken = new Label() { Content = curTokenText };
new InlineUIContainer(curToken, insertHere);
tokenList.Add(curToken);
```

Now i want to retrieve all the inline elements and convert them back to UIElement (Label in this case). Along with all the inline text. How can i achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over inlines like below to get back the labels:

```
List<UIElement> labels = new List<UIElement>();

foreach (var block in myRTB.Document.Blocks)
{
    if (block is Paragraph)
    {
        var paragraph = block as Paragraph;
        foreach (var inline in paragraph.Inlines)
        {
            if(inline is InlineUIContainer)
            {
    labels.Add(((InlineUIContainer)inline).Child);
            }
        }

    }
}
```